# Java Object Type to Protobuf

Tags: java, protocol-buffers, protobuf-java

Is there any way to serialize java Object type to protobuff and what would  proto file look like.

Desired functionality:

```
Object object = TutorialAPI.getObject();
ProtoMessage protoMessage = ProtoMessage.newBuilder()
    .setValue(object)
    .build;
```

Comment: What is the runtime type (class) of the object you want to serialize?

Comment: The Object in runtime will be String, Int or Float.

Answer (score 0):

You can serialize your object into JSON String, then use setValue.

```
Object object = TutorialAPI.getObject();
String json = convertToJson(object)
ProtoMessage protoMessage = ProtoMessage.newBuilder()
    .setValue(json)
    .build();
```

Comment: In the end this was exactly what i ended up doing, but it doesnt seem like a long term solution to use protobuf just so i can dump a bunch of JSON data in it.

Comment: Protobuf requires you to define the structure. So, if you don't want to define it beforehand, one option is to use JSON.